# Adding extra fields to GeoJSON

Tags: geojson

My app returns standard GeoJSON, always as a FeatureCollection.

When I display the GeoJSON in my front end, I want to zoom to show just the features in the file. I'd like to include an enclosing boundary box to make that easier:

```
{
    "boundaries": [12.3456, 78.9012, 34.5678, 90.1234],
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "value"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [...]
        }
    }]
}
```

Is it acceptable to non-standard fields like this? Is this valid GeoJSON or will third-party tools choke on it?

Comment: And yes, you *can* add non-standard fields (aka ["foreign members"](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7946#section-6.1)) but support will vary. Some software may ignore it, some may fail to parse the geojson.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-5) already allows you to add a `bbox` inside the feature collection.

> A GeoJSON object MAY have a member named "bbox" to include information on the coordinate range for its Geometries, Features, or FeatureCollections.

Comment: The standard is this https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7946#section-5 `A GeoJSON object MAY have a member named "bbox" to include information on the coordinate range for its Geometries, Features, or FeatureCollections.`

Comment: thanks, I was on my phone so adding the link was too hard